# Remove spaces except lines beginning with a specific pattern

Tags: text-processing

I want to remove all spaces from a file, except from every line beginning with the same pattern (pattern is "ORGANISM").

**Input:**

```
Cat; Dog; Squirrel
ORGANISM Animalus terrus
Sequence: ACGTACGTACGTACGTACGTACGTACGTACGTACGTACGTACGTACGT
```

**Output:**

```
Cat;Dog;Squirrel
ORGANISM Animalus terrus
Sequence:ACGTACGTACGTACGTACGTACGTACGTACGTACGTACGTACGTACGT
```

No more spaces in any line except the line starting with the characters "ORGANISM".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
sed '/^ORGANISM/!s/ //g' /path/to/input
```

This will remove all spaces on all lines that do *not* start with `ORGANISM`.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e '/^ORGANISM/n' -e 's/ //g'  < input > output
```

The first expression jumps to the `n`ext line if this one starts with `ORGANISM`, and if that didn't happen, `s`ubstitute all spaces with nothing (`g`lobally)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a perl version using negative lookahead `(?!ORGANISM)` to figure out if we need to perform substitution. `-p` flags allows automatic printing

```
$ perl -pe 's/[[:blank:]]//g if /^(?!ORGANISM).*/' input.txt                                                             
Cat;Dog;Squirrel
ORGANISM Animalus terrus
Sequence:ACGTACGTACGTACGTACGTACGTACGTACGTACGTACGTACGTACGT
```